# Qlik sense, Issues loading data

Tags: business-intelligence, qliksense

I have a Qlik Sense application with an obdc connection. When I try to select the columns in data load editor it appears as the second image. I can't find what is causing this error, my other apps are working fine. If I load few rows it works(1000) but loading the whole table (80000 rows) fails. Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Adding in your loadscript might help :)

Comment: @PinkFluffyUnicorn My loadscript is the auto-generated code created by clicking in the columns, the problem is that Qlik only load the fist letter on every cell.

Comment: @Qlik use "RAM" it could be that loading all rows takes too much ram, maybe you have others application absorbing ram